# ASP.NET: httpwebrequest date header workaround

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I'm trying to integrate with an API that requires the "Date" header in a web request. As you may well know, .NET has removed the ability to append or even display a default Date header in your request, so I was wondering about a workaround.

Here's the catch: you can't use TCPClients because I don't have "permissions" on my server for such a thing as sockets. Is there some way to "cheat" the system to fake a date header or to trick it into posting a Date header? Or should I just give up on this API?

Thanks...

(PS, language is VB.NET if you please :) )

Comment: On TCPClient: have you confirmed you don't have access to that particular API, talking to port 80?

Comment: I'm currently trying the same thing. I am continually getting error messages from Zeep saying "Message time differs to much from server clock or Date header was not supplied."

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the date problem, you just have to access the request directly as a HttpWebRequest. It seems like a simple answer but it worked.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Uri)  ;

request.Date = date;
request.Method = "POST";
```

Comment: Which .NET runtime supports that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the system will add a Date header with the current date and time. Do you need a different value for the header?

You may be able to add it by using request.Headers.AddWithoutValidate.

Comment: hey again john :) when i pull down all the request headers, the Date is not included. I need to send the date +7hrs to match GMT.

Comment: also, I can't access request.Headers.AddWithoutValidate because it is protected?

Comment: Crap. I thought I had it set to not show me protected members. Sorry. But on the Date, are you sure it sends the wrong thing, that your target won't understand it?

Comment: it doesn't send anything at all for the date... the headers i get are: Authorization: Zeep [api]:[hash]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: api.zeepmobile.com
Content-Length: 42
Connection: Keep-Alive

Comment: See http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet/2005-09/msg03097.html. He worked around the problem by using TCPClient.

Comment: I did some research on this, and I see no reason why the current date/time are not sent on every request. I opened https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=475082 about this issue.

Comment: wow, thanks... i'm interested to see what they have to say, if they say anything at all... as for the TCPClient, I saw that a while ago, but i can't use that method (as specified in the question)

Comment: I'll believe it when I see it, but they just changed the status on this Connect report to "Fixed".

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the fastest code in the world, but it might work for a while:

```
Type type = request.Headers.GetType();
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("AddWithoutValidate", 
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
method.Invoke(request.Headers, new [] { "Date", DateTime.Now.ToString() })
```

Just be aware that using reflection to access private or protected members is extremely fragile and can break with any update to .NET that MS does...

Comment: From my research, it seems this won't help. They don't even send the header with the current date/time, as documented.

Comment: BTW, I'm about to downvote this. Not that it was very bad, but to indicate to future readers that this did not contribute to the solution (since HttpWebRequest wasn't going to send the header no matter whether or not it was set)

Comment: Is this fixed in .NET 3.5 - the Date is being send on my code

Comment: Date with no-hack is not working in .NET 3.5, only in 4.0. I have to vote for this as it provides a good temporary solution!