# HttpWebRequest Date Header Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, httpwebrequest, date-format

I am using C# ASP.NET 4. So far as I can tell, the HttpWebRequest object is not using the format defined by [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) for the Date header. Is there a way to tell a DateTime class how I want the string representation to be formatted, or is there a way to set the Date header to a string? What I am seeing is: "11/5/2011 1:55:15 PM". The correct DateTime format string for HTTP requests is: @"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss G\MT".

I have tried this, It threw and error.

```
Request.Headers.Set("Date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss G\\MT"));
```

Update: Doh! Silly me. I was using the Date object and even tried to force the string I wanted. Thankfully that just lead me to trying something else.

```
Request.Headers.Get("Date")
```

I will leave this question up for those that may run into this silly problem I did. Critical thinking skills... I feel like a dope. >:|

Comment: See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/475082/http-date-request-header-is-not-sent-by-httpwebrequest

Comment: I know about that, but am under the impression that it applies to .NET < 4. I can set the Date header manually to DateTime.UtcNow in .NET 4. Also, in case anyone is wondering how I even came to stress so much about the Date header, it is because I am working with AWS and part of the Authorization involves using the Date header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead to get the string representation.

```
Request.Headers.Get("Date")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to set date header format except using reflection

Have a look at these links for how to use reflection workaround

[c-sharp-httpwebrequest-date-header-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497177/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-date-header-formatting)

[asp-net-httpwebrequest-date-header-workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140553/asp-net-httpwebrequest-date-header-workaround)