# 403 forbidden error - Accessing Amazon S3 bucket using Http GET Request in c#

Tags: c#, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am writing an c# code that is trying to access the Amazon S3 bucket through REST calls. 
The code makes a get request to an xml file created in the s3 bucket.

I am using the secret key and access Id to create a signature that will be used in the authorization header.

The Signature I created is based on Amazon's documentation,
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

I have provided permissions for authenticated requests to access the xml file in the s3 bucket.

The Code I am using,

```
string AccessId = "xyz";
string SecretKey = "xyz";
string bucketName = "bucket";
string filename = "filename.xml";
string httpDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +0000\n");
string StringtoSign = "GET\n"
                      + "\n"
                      + "\n"
                      + httpDate + "\n"  
                      + "/bucketName/filename.xml";

//Creating Signature
     Encoding e_UTF = new UTF8Encoding();
     Encoding e_ASCI = new ASCIIEncoding();
     byte[] key_new= e_ASCI.GetBytes(SecretKey);
     byte[] message_new = e_UTF.GetBytes(StringtoSign);
     HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(key_new);
     byte[] final=myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(message_new);
     string AWSSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(final);

// Sending request
HttpWebRequest request =    (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://"+bucketname+".s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"+filename);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "AWS"+ " " + AccessId + ":" + AWSSignature);
try
{
    // Getting response
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    String ResStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(ResStr);
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    var Resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
    Stream new_str=Resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader stred = new StreamReader(new_str);
    MessageBox.Show(stred.ReadToEnd().ToString());
}
```

The Same Code works fine if I set the permissions for the xml file as public. So it has got to do something with the signature. 
I am not sure what am doing wrong. It would be great if someone can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell S3 what date/time you used to calculate the signature by sending either a Date or X-Amz-Date header. Your code's signing the request as if you were sending a Date header, so you should ask the HttpWebRequest to send a matching Date header (and be sure to format it the same way the HttpWebRequest will):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
string httpDate = now.ToString("r");

...

request.Date = now;
```

Alternatively, you may want to consider using the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/), which will take care of generating a correct signature for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to set the date header using the code mentioned in this thread, [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497177/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-date-header-formatting). I am now getting "signature not matching" message along with the response. I tried another method using **query string authentication** and am able to send authentication requests properly. But still not able to send authentication using **Authorisation Header**.