# C# reading JSON from web API

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to read data from this API [API Wykazu podatników VAT](https://www.gov.pl/web/kas/api-wykazu-podatnikow-vat)

Thru HttpWebRequest it's working:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://wl-test.mf.gov.pl:9091/wykaz-podatnikow/api/search/nips/3245174504?date=2019-09-27");
    try
    {
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
        using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
            String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // log errorText
        }
        throw;
    }
```

But when I try it thru WebClient:

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("nips", "3245174504");
    client.Headers.Add("date", "2019-09-27");
    var response = client.DownloadString("https://wl-test.mf.gov.pl:9091/wykaz-podatnikow/api/search/nips/");
    Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
```

I got this error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.ArgumentException: The 'date' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
>       Parameter name: name
>          at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ThrowOnRestrictedHeader(String headerName)
>          at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Add(String name, String value)
>          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_Headers(WebHeaderCollection value)
>          at System.Net.WebClient.CopyHeadersTo(WebRequest request)
>          at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
>          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
>          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
>          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)

How should I format the second Date parameter?

Comment: Are you sure you have to add these the parameters in the header? Once it is a "get" request it is supposed to be on the url like in the first example.

Comment: If you want to change the date parameter check this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497177/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-date-header-formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the newer HTTPClient as it is specifically created for API calls -

```
    using (var x = new HttpClient())
    {
        var y = x.GetAsync("https://wl-test.mf.gov.pl:9091/wykaz-podatnikow/api/search/nips/3245174504?date=2019-09-27").Result;
        var json = y.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

Just to add, please don't use .Result, instead use the async/await operators.

Comment: But _not like this_ ! See https://contrivedexample.com/2017/07/01/using-httpclient-as-it-was-intended-because-youre-not/ or https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ or https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Comment: yes sorry edited that just did that for sample purpose only

Comment: Hi, what is that "date=2019-09-27" is it a registered date of that  number ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you mistaking request headers with Query Parameters? if so you might want the following instead:

`https://wl-test.mf.gov.pl:9091/wykaz-podatnikow/api/search?nips=3245174504&date=2019-09-27`